# How to deinstall Talking Book

Tags: uninstallation

I cannot find [the app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tbdaisy&rdid=com.tbdaisy) in the list of apps. And it starts randomly. I want to get rid of it. How?

Comment: Of course, that worked. Thanks. I an used to holding the app icon and drag it to uninstall. I did not think of this obvious option.

Comment: What the heck is that thing, anyway? The Play Store description looks like it was generated with a Markov chain. o_O

Comment: It is supposed to read DAISY books. Basically audio files but you are supposed to be able to easily navigate through chapters. I ended up using [Dolphin EasyReader](https://yourdolphin.com/easyreader) on my computer to have the one DAISY book read I wanted to have read. If there is a working (!) Android app for this I would like to know it. I know [this list](http://www.daisy.org/tools/1463) but I do not want to test all of them by myself. Experience wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to play store, locate the app there and choose to uninstall !